# Splitting payload after fixed number of decimals

Tags: javascript, node-red

I need to split a payload in Node-RED whenever it is longer than a certain number of characters, and after a certain number of decimals.

I am working on a project where a sensor is providing feedback to Node-RED, but it sometimes puts two outputs together, and I can't seem to find a way to split the resulting data into two parts at a position which is not at the decimal point, but a number of digits AFTER the decimal point.

At the moment, I am scrapping the wrong outputs using
`if (msg.payload.length < 11){return msg;}`
so that only single output results are processed further, while anything else is discarded.

Output can be like `123.4567123.4687` instead of `123.4567`and `123.4687`.
Note that the problem only occurs sometimes (something like every 100th measurement).
Note that the number of digits BEFORE the decimal point is not necessarily the same every time, so it is not just a matter of splitting after a certain number of digits from the first.

Comment: `foo.match(/([0-9]+\.[0-9]{4})/g)` …?

Comment: Do you know anything else about the readings ? Like the maximum difference between two consecutive readings or the precision of each reading (the number of digits after the decimal point) ?

Answer (score 0):

If the number of digits after the decimal point is constant you could use a regular expression to extract the needed values, for example:

```
var input = "123.4567123.4678";
var results = input.match(/\d+\.\d{4}/g);
```

results is an array that contains the two values as strings: `[ '123.4567', '123.4678' ]`

The Regex globally matches one or more digits (`\d+`) followed by a point (`\.`) followed by four digits (`\d{4}`)